# How to fix 404 'Not Found' error when attempting to send large amount of data to web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, httpclient, webclient

I have a web service that allows a client to get queries from a database and run them on the client machine, posting the results back to the web service. These results are parsed from a Datatable to xml and then sent using WebClient.UploadValues. I can send and receive queries/results as long as they are small (only returning several thousand rows), but when the query returns hundreds of thousands of results, the xml string becomes quite large (the one in particular I'm working with now is 70mb) and the web service returns 404 Not Found.

I've already increased maxAllowedContentLength, maxRequestLength, and executionTimeout in the web.config for the web service. It just seems like the client doesn't even attempt to push the data to the web service before it gets that error. Is there any way to tell what the true problem is (limitation of the xml string variable?)? The code for sending the data to the web service is below.

```
    Using wc As New WebClient()
        Try
            Dim nvc As New NameValueCollection
            nvc.Add("params", myParameters)
            wc.UploadValues(URI, nvc)

        Catch ex As WebException
            eLog.WriteEntry("Application", My.Application.Info.AssemblyName + " - " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
```

I've also tried this method:

```
    Try
        Dim client As New HttpClient()
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)
        Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URI)
        request.Content = New StringContent(myParameters)

        Dim response = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)

    Catch ex As HttpRequestException
        eLog.WriteEntry("Application", My.Application.Info.AssemblyName + " - " + ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 6 hours, I randomly decided to rearrange the maxAllowedContentLength in the web.config and it fixed the issue. I don't know the correct positioning for the "security" tag, but putting it like this solved my issue:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Home.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```